# Merge several tomcat access-logs lines in one line

Tags: linux, tomcat, sles

I need your help. I want to log the access on my **Apache Tomcat** webserver on **SLES 12**. He is running and he is logging normally. But when I visit the site, tomcat is writing 8 lines into the `localhost_access_log.txt` file. Like this:

```
10.XXX.XX.XXX - - [27/Jul/2016:08:28:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11250 10.XXX.XX.XXX - - [27/Jul/2016:08:28:29 +0200] "GET /tomcat.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5576 10.XXX.XX.XXX - - [27/Jul/2016:08:28:29 +0200] "GET /tomcat.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5103 10.XXX.XX.XXX - - [27/Jul/2016:08:28:29 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630 10.XXX.XX.XXX - - [27/Jul/2016:08:28:29 +0200] "GET /bg-nav.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1401 10.XXX.XX.XXX - - [27/Jul/2016:08:28:29 +0200] "GET /asf-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 17811 10.XXX.XX.XXX - - [27/Jul/2016:08:28:29 +0200] "GET /bg-middle.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1918 10.XXX.XX.XXX - - [27/Jul/2016:08:28:29 +0200] "GET /bg-button.png HTTP/1.1" 200 713 10.XXX.XX.XXX - - [27/Jul/2016:08:28:29 +0200] "GET /bg-upper.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3103 10.XXX.XX.XXX - - [27/Jul/2016:08:28:29 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 206 21630 10.XXX.XX.XXX - - [27/Jul/2016:08:28:29 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
```

The same when I logged in as an admin, then tomcat write 5 lines.

```
10.XXX.XX.XXX - - [27/Jul/2016:10:37:01 +0200] "GET /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 2473 10.XXX.XX.XXX - admin [27/Jul/2016:10:37:02 +0200] "GET /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 200 7010 10.XXX.XX.XXX - - [27/Jul/2016:10:37:03 +0200] "GET /manager/images/tomcat.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 2066 10.XXX.XX.XXX - - [27/Jul/2016:10:37:03 +0200] "GET /manager/images/asf-logo.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 7279 10.XXX.XX.XXX - - [27/Jul/2016:10:37:03 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
```

Now my question: It’s possible, that tomcat only write one line per access? Or that tomcat write the log in a per-sonal format? Because I want to analyses the access-logs with **graylog2** and grayog has some problem with this.

Comment: Title is too broad hence unhelpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late but still.

I don't think you can reduce amount of line in log file, but for analysis you can filter out some lines

```
egrep -v ' /tomcat.[^\b]{3}|/favicon.ico| /[^\.]*.png' acces.log > filtered.log
```

where

- `egrep -v` remove from output lines matching pattern
- `/tomcat.[^\b]{3}` : a blank, /tomcat string a dot and 3 non blank
- `/favicon.ico` straightforward
- `/[^\.]*.png` a blank a slash, any number of non dot and png

of course log analyser might have some pre built filter, or you might have to spend some time customizing it.